# Path not being honored?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I have the following in my ***`.bash_profile`***:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
# Prompt
export PS1="\h:\W$ "

# Standard path
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin"

# Android
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/.android"

export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/"
```

I verified the path with:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:/opt/android-sdk/tools/:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```

My local build of Emacs is in ***`/usr/local/bin`***. I just built and installed it:

```
$ which emacs
/usr/local/bin/emacs
```

When I run Emacs, I get the one from ***`/usr/bin`***:

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
...
$ /usr/bin/emacs --version
GNU Emacs 22.1.1
...
$ /usr/local/bin/emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
...
```

Why am I having trouble with the paths? Why is OS X ignoring them? How can I use my copy of Emacs in ***`/usr/local/bin/emacs`*** *without* specifying the full path?

Comment: If you open a new terminal tab, does the problem persist there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I had to reboot the machine to have the changes take effect. A logoff/logon may have had the same effect, but I did not try it.

Comment: If you had cleared the hash table then the new emacs would have been called. No need tp logout or reboot.

Comment: @fd0 - Forgive my ignorance... What hash table are you talking about? What does it have to do with a path or a program?

Comment: The hash table is a shell feature that records the full path of a command to memory after a PATH lookup. Subsequent calls to a command are first checked in the hash table instead of having to use a PATH lookup. More info can be found with the command `help hash`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to amend your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin`
is ahead of `/usr/bin` do the following:

1. execute `. ~/.bash_profile`
2. execute `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in the current shell
3. restart Terminal

You may also want to amend `/etc/paths` so that `/usr/local/bin` is listed before `/usr/bin`. You'll need to sudo your editor in order to do that.

```
sudo open -t /etc/paths
```

Bear in mind that if you edit `/etc/paths` there is a risk that non-terminal applications may pick up your locally build version. Just FYI.

A little more information on paths.

1. `/bin` (and `/sbin`) were intended for programs that needed to be on a small `/` partition before the larger `/usr`, etc. partitions were mounted. These days, it mostly serves as a standard location for key programs like `/bin/sh`, although the original intent may still be relevant for e.g. installations on small embedded devices.
2. `/sbin`, as distinct from `/bin`, is for system management programs (not normally used by ordinary users) needed before `/usr` is mounted.
3. `/usr/bin` is for distribution-managed normal user programs.
4. There is a `/usr/sbin` with the same relationship to `/usr/bin` as `/sbin` has to `/bin`.
5. `/usr/local/bin` is for normal user programs not managed by the distribution package manager, e.g. locally compiled packages. You should not install them into `/usr/bin` because future distribution upgrades may modify or delete them without warning.
6. `/usr/local/sbin`, as you can probably guess at this point, is to `/usr/local/bin` as `/usr/sbin` to `/usr/bin`.

This source helps explain the [filesystem hierarchy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) on a deeper level.

And you might find this [article on the use and abuse of `/usr/local/bin`](http://aplawrence.com/Opinion/religion.html) interesting as well.

Comment: The OP already had `/usr/local/bin` at the beginning of PATH…

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have noticed that too. One may (or may not) wish to omit according command at will. BTW, who is OP? :)

Comment: Original Poster :-) BTW, I didn't even realize that people go into holy wars over the use of `/usr/local`.